# How many non-isomorphic full binary trees can n nodes generate?

Tags: algorithm, math, tree

Isomorphism means that arbitary sub-trees of a full binary tree swapping themselves can be identical to another one.

The answer is definitely not Catalan Number, because the amount of Catalan Number counts the isomorphic ones.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by `n` nodes you mean `n` internal nodes.  So it will have `2n+1` vertices, and `2n` edges.

Next, we can put an order on binary trees as follows.  A tree with more nodes is bigger.  If two trees have the same number of nodes, compare the left side, and break ties by comparing the right.  If two trees are equal in this order, it isn't hard to show by induction that they are the same tree.

For your problem, we can assume that for each isomorphism class we are only interested in the *maximal* tree in that isomorphism class.  Note that this means that both the left and the right subtrees must also be maximal in their isomorphism classes, and the left subtree must be the same as or bigger than the right.

So suppose that `f(n)` is the number of non-isomorphic binary trees with `n` nodes.  We can now go recursively.  Here are our cases:

1. `n=0` there is one, the empty tree.
2. `n=1` there is one.  A node with 2 leaves.
3. `n > 1`.  Let us iterate over `m`, the number on the right.  If `2m+1 < n` then there are `f(m)` maximal trees on the right, `f(n-m-1)` on the left, and all of those are maximal for `f(m) * f(n-m-1)`.  If `2m+1 = n` then we want a maximal tree on the right with `m` nodes, and a maximal tree on the left with `m` nodes, and the one on the right has to be smaller than or equal to the one on the left.  But there is a well-known formula for how many ways to do that, which is `f(m) * (f(m) + 1) / 2`.  And finally we can't have `n < 2m+1` because in that case we don't have a maximal tree.

Using this, you should be able to write a recursive function to calculate the answer.

**UPDATE** Here is such a function:

```
cache = {0: 1, 1:1}
def count_nonisomorphic_full_trees (n):
    if n not in cache:
        answer = 0
        for m in range(n):
            c = count_nonisomorphic_full_trees(m)
            if n < m+m+1:
                break
            elif n == m+m+1:
                answer = answer + c*(c+1)//2
            else:
                d = count_nonisomorphic_full_trees(n-m-1)
                answer = answer + c*d
        cache[n] = answer
    return cache[n]
```

Note that it starts off slower than the Catalan numbers but still grows exponentially.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, it's really helpful. I came up with the problem when I was reading [Leetcode 849](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-possible-full-binary-trees/). I am also curious about how to output the list of trees and visualize them in our non-isomorphic case like the example on Leetcode. Looking forward your answer!

Comment: P.S. I’ll be appreciated if you could provide some sources about the “well-known formula” you mentioned above.

Comment: @wilton_hwang See https://byjus.com/maths/triangular-numbers/ for the formula.  Actually generating the trees sounds like a fun challenge.  I will have to think about that.

Comment: Suggesting using `//2` instead of `/2`, to avoid floating-point outputs. See also https://oeis.org/A001190

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks, fixed.  I also looked at generating specific trees, and sadly there is a complex binary search that is more work than my curiosity justifies.